# How to run an Electron .exe app on Linux?

Tags: linux, electron, wine

I'm trying to run an application build with Electron on Linux. They app maker offers an .exe installation file. So I figured I'd install it in WINE, but I seem to be missing something the app needs to run.

Since the install is an .exe, do I need WINE? And if I need WINE, what do I need to install to make the app work? I have tried two Electron apps, both only downloadable as a .exe install file.

Comment: https://www.electronjs.org/docs/development/build-instructions-linux you should build it to work for linux , .exe i think could work on mac and sure for windows in same build command, but go through the link to build on linux

Answer (score -1):

Electron adds os native calls, so .exe files usually do not work. WINE is not able to emulate all of those calls, so if it isn't working for you, then you are out of luck I guess. Look for apps that offer linux versions, like https://www.electronjs.org/apps/camunda-modeler. If you have access to the repository, chances are they build it using [electron-builder](https://www.electron.build/cli). You can just build it yourself with the command `electron-builder build --linux` in most cases